# Javascript - Print a full html block

Tags: javascript, php, html, shortcut

I have this php code for write down list of html elements and dynamically change the text using an array.
I want to accomplish this with a Javascript code, How do I do that?

```
    <?php
    $services = ["Storage", "network", "Virtual Machine", "server","firewall","firewall","users","backup"];
    $servicesName = ["Storage", "network", "Virtual Machine", "server","firewall","firewall","users","backup"];
$learnMore - ["Some Brief Description"];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($services); $i++) {
      $x = $i;
      echo "<div class='flexbox-item'>
        <div class='learnmore'>
        <img src='sourceimages/icons/speech/learnmore.png' alt='LearnMore'>
        <div>$learnMore</div>
        </div>
        <div class='maskshape'></div>
        <div class='shape'><img src='sourceimages/icons/services/$services[$i].png' alt='$servicesName[$i]'></div>
        <div class='number'><span>0".++$x."</span></div>
        <div class='title'><span>$servicesName[$i]</span></div>
      </div>";
```

Comment: seems like you posted only half code.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You are supposed to try yourself first. We are happy to answer questions when you encounter a specific problem!

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can print any html by below function. Pass html string in it as parameter.

```
function print(htmlToPass) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600'); //create dummy window
    mywindow.document.write(htmlToPass); //write your html in it.
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

Ex. to call function.

`var htmltoprint = '<html><body><h1>anything you want to print</h1></body></html>';`
`print(htmltoprint);`